# Passing column names in R function containing is.na() and median

Tags: r

I have data with Income,spending,population and state. Income, spending and population has missing values.

I have created a for loop to replace the missing values by median which is calculated state-wise. However I have to run the for loop separately for Income, Spending and population. I tried to create a function to pass just the column names but it is giving me an error with is.na(). Here is the for loop

```
for (i in (unique(data$State))) {
data$Income[is.na(data$Income) & data$State==i] <-
 median(data$Income[data$State==i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

In place of income I tried making a function and passing x.. but it is not working. Can someone help me achieve this function. I tried a few things but it gave me an error with is.na

```
Med_sub <- function(x){
  for (i in (unique(data$State))) {
    data$x[is.na(data$x)&data$State==i] <- median(data$x[data$State==i], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}

Med_sub(Income)
Med_sub(Population)
```

I am new to R. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide a working dataset?

Comment: what error message does it give you? is your data truly `NA` or are there blanks / characters?

Comment: You can take this for example:
data <- data.frame(
  State = c("TX","TN","VA","NY","TX","TN","VA","NY"),
  Income = c(120,NA,NA,102,244,145,153,NA),
  Population = c(100,200,300,400,100,200,300,400),
  Spending = c(NA,20,40,NA,10,50,NA,80)
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a base R two-liner with `ave` (the inline aggregate function that slices numeric columns by factors) and `ifelse` all wrapped in a `sapply` loop:

```
median_fill <- function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), median(x, na.rm=TRUE), x)

data[c("Income","spending","population")] <- sapply(data[c("Income","spending","population")],
                                                    function(i) ave(i, data$state, FUN=median_fill))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` three-liner:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  mutate_all(.funs = funs(coalesce(., median(., na.rm=TRUE))))
```